# Apache Running but no site loading

Tags: apache2

Apache is running properly on my server, when I'm doing a ping on the server address i'm getting only the following

```
PING 45.56.87.123 (45.56.87.123) 56(84) bytes of data
```

none of my site is loading, i have something dummy at `http://45.56.87.123/test/index.html` but can't even access the page there,

my iptables:

```
[root@localhost test]# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             loopback/8           reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 5/min burst 5 LOG level debug prefix "iptables denied: "
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

any help on how i can get the server running properly ?

Comment: Since guessing is the only thing we can do I'd guess it's a firewall problem.

Comment: port 80 is not open

Comment: i've added my iptables, any guess

Comment: @Orphans, doing "telnet localhost 80" works

Comment: Well, your IP does not answer my telnet requests.

Comment: yes, it's not, i checked this, any idea why can't do so from outside ?

Comment: "none of my site is loading" is not a useful diagnostic. The browser connects but doesn't receive a response? The browser reports an error? A blank page? Not the page you expect? If you want help you'll need to learn how to accurately describe the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Since I can't add a comment (low reputation) I'll just try pasting the answer. Basically connection to your server is timing out:

```
$ nc -vz 45.56.87.123 443
nc: connect to 45.56.87.123 port 443 (tcp) failed: Connection timed out

$ nc -vz 45.56.87.123 80
nc: connect to 45.56.87.123 port 80 (tcp) failed: Connection timed ou
```

From the `iptables` rules I see above I haven't noticed anything wrong so you may try checking if your service is listening on that port first:

```
lsof -i :80
lsof -i :443
```

If not than there's your problem. If yes, you're left with firewall issue so you may try restarting `iptables`. Also, which OS are you using?

Is connection from localhost working? Like:

```
curl http://45.56.87.123/test/index.html
```

or

```
nc -vz 127.0.0.1 80
nc -vz 127.0.0.1 443
```